# PointCloud subscriber/publisher types

Tags: ros, pcl, nodelet, messages, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When working with PointClouds, I usually subscribe to a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` topic, and convert to a `pcl::PointCloud` inside my code. Then, once I'm done mainpulating the cloud, I convert it back to a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2` to publish it, using these functions:

```
pcl::fromROSMsg
pcl::toROSMsg
```

My first question is: what is the cost of using these functions? I am assuming there's a memcpy involved, which (when dealing with kinect data) is probably not negligible.

Second: is there a way to avoid this, by directly subscribing/publishing `pcl::PointCloud`  types? I believe that there is a publisher/subscriber for pcl types, but I'm not sure whether it *actually* saves time, or does the same conversion/memcpy behind the scenes.

Thanks,
Ivan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9538/pointcloud-subscriber/publisher-types/) by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4954 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The conversion to and from PCL datatypes is quite computationally expensive.  I have observed something like 100ms for a conversion of a Kinect frame on a 1Ghz Atom core.

To avoid this you can use direct publication of pcl datatypes and [nodelets](http://ros.org/wiki/nodelet).  A very simple example of a nodelet which does this is in the pointcloud_to_laserscan package is [cloud_throttle.cpp](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/2154e9c1c701/pointcloud_to_laserscan/src/cloud_throttle.cpp)

When publishing over the network the Kinect data was unusable.

Using nodelets I was able to take processing of the Kinect from 10Hz and 150% cpu to 30Hz and 87% cpu on an Atom by publishing using the exact same data type.  Here's  a [launch file](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/2154e9c1c701/turtlebot_bringup/robot.launch) which brings up the kinect and processes the data inside the same process using nodelets.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-12-19**:
what about the second part of the question? when publishing / subscribing directly with pcl PointCloud, does it first convert to sensors_msgs::PointCloud2 then serialize, then deserialize and convert to PCL? Or does it serialize deserialize directly from / to PCL? I am not using nodelets.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-19**:
If ti does require conversion it will directly convert to the wire format to or from the pcl datatype.